# Get contents after last slash

Tags: c#, string-parsing

I have strings that have a directory in the following format:

```
C://hello//world
```

How would I extract everything after the last `/` character (`world`)?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
string path = "C://hello//world";
int pos = path.LastIndexOf("/") + 1;
Console.WriteLine(path.Substring(pos, path.Length - pos)); // prints "world"
```

The `LastIndexOf` method performs the same as `IndexOf`.. but from the end of the string.

Comment: Since C# 8.0 you can also use the range operator. 

```C#
Console.WriteLine(path[pos..]);
```
For reference, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges

Comment: Good thing to notice how this works when there is no slash in the string. It returns the whole string, which is usually correct. Also, the Substring method does not need the second parameter, it returns everything till the end of string automatically.

Answer (score 53):

`using System.Linq;`

```
var s = "C://hello//world";
var last = s.Split('/').Last();
```

Answer (score 16):

There is a static class for working with Paths called [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx).

You can get the full Filename with [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx).

or

You can get the Filename without Extension with [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx).

Comment: I had thought about that, but notice that the OP seems to not be focusing on a file, but a directory

Comment: Caution with this: it won't work if the filename contains a colon : e.g. //depot/some:file.ext 
GetFileName will only return file.ext which is not what you might expect. This is not a valid path on windows systems but the OP didn't specify the OS.

Comment: @JustinPihony it does not matter if it is a file or directory. `Path.GetFileName("C://hello//world")` will return `world`.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
string worldWithPath = "C://hello//world";
string world = worldWithPath.Substring(worldWithPath.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Comment: This is the same solution already posted by Simon Whitehead (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15857606/2029849), besides of an explicitly given length in the `Substring` method call.

Comment: This is smarter solution instead @abto

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest looking at the `System.IO` namespace as it seems that you might want to use that. There is DirectoryInfo and FileInfo that might be of use here, also. Specifically [DirectoryInfo's Name property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.name.aspx)

```
var directoryName = new DirectoryInfo(path).Name;
```